# Getting entropy in decision trees more than 1

Tags: decision-trees

My decision tree entropy is coming more than 1 when I'm calculating it manually. Not sure if there's some calculation error.

Trying it on the [Iris dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris).

If I split on sepal length at 6.5 cm, my split looks like this
[image]

Now I'm calculating entropy with this formula with the following code below. The problem is that I'm getting entropy values > 1
[image]

The labels to the left of the split look like this

```
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]))
```

The labels to the right look like this

```
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]))
```

The code I'm using to calculate entropy is this

```
    def entropy(labels): #This function calculates entropy according to the formula posted above
        uniques = np.unique(labels,return_counts=True)
        unique_probs = uniques[1]/sum(uniques[1])


        entropy = sum(unique_probs *-np.log2(unique_probs))
        return entropy
    

    def overall_entropy(split):
        count_below, count_above = len(split['below'][0]), len(split['above'][0]) #split is a dictionary that has 2 values below and above with the X and y arrays. This line just calculates the total length on the values

        prob_below, prob_above = count_below / (count_below + count_above), count_above / (count_below + count_above)
        overall_entropy = prob_below * entropy(split['below'][1]) + prob_above * entropy(split['above'][1]) #This line calculates total entropy of the split by combining individual entropies below and above the split

        return overall_entropy
```

For this particular split, my entropy comes out to be 1.4, which should not be possible. I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake. Please help

I'm posting how the variable `split` looks on a subset of the data in case it's confusing
[image]

Comment: Why do you think entropy (for multiclass classification) cannot be larger than 1?

Comment: That's what most of the decision tree theory I have read says. I understand max entropy of a split is log k (k being the number of classes) and can be greater than 1. But my understanding from reading some of the theory is that overall entropy of the system is less than 1. I'm not sure if this is true, which is what my question is.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thinking about it, the overall entropy is just a weighted average of the entropy of the individual splits, and there theoretically isn't any constraint on it being > 1. I'm just confirming that my thinking is right.